# Rails API not receiving fetch POST data from body

Tags: fetch, rails-api

I have a route in Rails API '/api/pay'. My client side post request successfully hits the controller action, however nothing I send in the `body: JSON.stringify('...')` gets through to the back-end. Other post requests I have made work just fine with the same format.

```
export const payForItem = (payData) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(payForItemStart());
    // ?userID=${data.userID}&adID=${data.adID}&price=${data.price}
    const data = {userID: payData.userID, adID: payData.adID, price: payData.price}    
    fetch(`/api/pay`, {
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

Here is what payData looks like.
[image: fetch payData]
Rails Api back-end params
[image: Rails API]

Answer (score 3):

Probably you've got typo in headers section. Should be plural header**S** with s:

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: Ha, if that’s the case then thank you much. I’m going to go back to that project pull it down, and see if that’s the case.